# Do the subsets of the integers divisible by 3, leave a remainder of 1, and leave a remainder of 2 when divided by 3 partition the set of integers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If you have 3 subsets of the integers: the set of integers divisible by 3, the set of integers leaving a remainder of 1 when divided by 3, and the set of integers leaving a remainder of 2 when divided by 3, do they partition the set of integers? The reason I am asking this is because everywhere I've looked I have found conflicting answers on whether the remainder of dividing a negative number by a positive number is negative or positive. (ex: What is the remainder of dividing -3 by 5, -3 or 2?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a partition.

When unsure, check the definition.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder):

> Given an integer $a$ and a non-zero integer $d$, it can be shown that there exist unique integers $q$ and $r$, such that $a = qd + r$ and $0 \le r < |d|$. The number $q$ is called the quotient, while r is called the remainder.

> The remainder, as defined above, is called the least positive remainder or simply the remainder

$$-3=(-1)(5)+2$$

$2$ is the remainder.